Angular - Unit test rxjs timer with default value
I have a component that uses rxjs to display a countdown timer. It has a default starting duration of 60 seconds, but can be overridden via input.
I am trying to build a unit test that verifies:

the default starting duration
that the timer is correctly initialized and begins counting down

Heres the component:
/**
 * Component for showing a timer counting down from a number of seconds.<br>
 * Default duration is 60 seconds when no value is provided.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'bevtech-countdown-seconds',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe, CountdownComponent],
  template: `
    <bevtech-countdown [value]="secondsRemaining() | async" />s
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CountdownSecondsComponent {
  /**
   * The value to begin counting down from.
   */
  duration = input<number|undefined>(60);

  /**
   * Event to emit when timer has reached zero.
   */
  finished = output<void>();

  /**
   * Reacts to changes to the {@link duration} input. <br>
   * On Change, generates a new Observable starting from the specified duration.
   * @protected
   */
  readonly secondsRemaining = computed(() => {
    const duration = this.duration();

    if (duration) {
      return timer(0, 1000)
        .pipe(
          map(value => duration - value), // Subtract the emitted value from the countdown duration
          takeWhile(value => value >= 0), // Take values until the countdown reaches 0
          finalize(() => this.finished.emit()) // Emit dismiss event on countdown finished
        );
    } else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  });
}

According to ChatGPT, and everything I know, a unit test like this should suffice:
it('should display the correct countdown value', fakeAsync(() => {
  // Set the duration to 10 seconds
  component.duration.next(10);

  // Trigger change detection to start the countdown
  fixture.detectChanges();

  // Wait for the first tick of the countdown
  tick(1000);

  // Verify that the countdown value is displayed correctly
  expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.countdown')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('9s');

  // Wait for the second tick of the countdown
  tick(1000);

  // Verify that the countdown value has decreased
  expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.countdown')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('8s');
}));

However, before the first tick() call, I see that the secondsRemaining signal is triggered and the initial value of 10 is set, but then it immediately jumps into the finalize call and just ends.
This results in the first expect() call to fail saying the text value is "" meaning nothing ever got updated.
Is there something im missing, or a better way to implement the timer in order to properly test this functionality?

you dont need async pipe because secondsRemaining is a signal     <bevtech-countdown [value]="secondsRemaining()" />
